# How to calculate total experience from ExperienceHistory table in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using `S_ResumeWorkHistory` table and storing data like

```
CREATE TABLE S_ResumeWorkHistory (
    ResumeID int,
    FromMonth int,
    FromYear int,
    ToMonth int,
    ToYear int,
    CurrentlyWorking varchar(1)
)

INSERT INTO S_ResumeWorkHistory
    (ResumeID, FromMonth, FromYear, ToMonth, ToYear, CurrentlyWorking)
VALUES 
    (17, 6,  2015, 10, 2016, 'N'),
    (17, 10, 2016, -1,   -1, 'Y')
```

I want total experience like

ResumeId, Experience

17, 3 years 3 months

I tried this query

```
select 
    SUM(convert(int,DATEDIFF(MONTH, FromMonth+'/1/'+FromYear, (CASE CurrentlyWorking WHEN 'N' THEN ToMonth+'/1/'+ToYear ELSE GETDATE() END))/12)),
    SUM(convert(int,DATEDIFF(MONTH, FromMonth+'/1/'+FromYear, (CASE CurrentlyWorking WHEN 'N' THEN ToMonth+'/1/'+ToYear ELSE GETDATE() END)) % 12))
FROM S_ResumeWorkHistory
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question, you may try with the following approach. First, get difference between from and to dates, using `DATEFROMPARTS()` and `DATEDIFF()`, then calculate that difference as years and months.

Input

```
CREATE TABLE S_ResumeWorkHistory (
    ResumeID int,
    FromMonth int,
    FromYear int,
    ToMonth int,
    ToYear int,
    CurrentlyWorking varchar(1)
)
INSERT INTO S_ResumeWorkHistory
    (ResumeID, FromMonth, FromYear, ToMonth, ToYear, CurrentlyWorking)
VALUES 
    (17, 6,  2015, 10, 2016, 'N'),
    (17, 10, 2016, -1,   -1, 'Y')
```

Statement

```
;WITH MonthsCTE AS (
    SELECT 
        ResumeId,
        CASE 
            WHEN CurrentlyWorking = 'N' THEN DATEDIFF(month, DATEFROMPARTS(FromYear, FromMonth, 1), DATEFROMPARTS(ToYear, ToMonth, 1))
            ELSE DATEDIFF(month, DATEFROMPARTS(FromYear, FromMonth, 1), GETDATE())
        END AS Months
    FROM S_ResumeWorkHistory
)
SELECT
    ResumeId,
    (CONVERT(nvarchar(100), SUM(Months) / 12)) + ' years, ' +
    (CONVERT(nvarchar(100), SUM(Months) % 12)) + ' months' AS Experience
FROM MonthsCTE
GROUP BY ResumeId
```

Output

```
ResumeId    Experience
17          3 years, 9 months
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Zhorov for your time